consultas mysql con mas de dos tablas
estoy haciendo consultas en MySQL y tengo 4 tablas,  factura, dvi, rbd y cdn, factura está relacionada con dvi, rbd y cdn, quiero hacer una consulta que me muestre los valores de la factura junto a los valores de su respectivo dvi, cdn y rbd. No tengo problema en la consulta sencilla, es decir al unir factura y dvi, o factura y cdn. El problema es mostrar todo junto al hacer la siguiente consulta :
select * from factura 
join cdn on (factura.cdn = cdn.Id_cdn) 
inner join rbd on (factura.rbd = rbd.Id_rbd) ;


create table CDN(
Id_CDN int primary key auto_increment,
num_CDN INT,
detalle varchar(100),
val_CDN INT
);

create table RBD(
Id_RBD int primary key auto_increment,
num_RBD INT,
detalle varchar(100),
val_RBD INT
);

create table DVI(
Id_DVI int primary key auto_increment,
num_DVI INT,
detalle varchar(100),
val_DVI INT
);
drop table factura;
create table Factura(
id_Factura int auto_increment primary key,
NumFactura INT NOT NULL,
Detalle varchar(30) NOT NULL,
VALOR int NULL,
Clientecod smallint NOT NULL,
rbd int null,
cdn int null,
dvi int null,
foreign key (Clientecod) references CLIENTE(Codigo_ter),
foreign key (rbd) references RBD(Id_RBD),
foreign key (cdn) references cdn(Id_CDN),
foreign key (dvi) references dvi(Id_DVI)
);


estas son mis tablas:

No me queda claro, solo quieres unir las 3 tablas durante la consulta? Que te impide usar más JOIN para eso?

Cual es el problema??

No coincide la información que está en la imagen con la estructura en SQL, faltan datos o algunas columnas tienen nombres distintos. Por otro lado dices que "El problema es mostrar todo junto..." ¿y cuál es ese problema?

solo debo unir las tres tablas, no sé si tengo mal la consulta, por que al realizr select * from factura
join cdn on (factura.cdn = cdn.Id_cdn)
inner join rbd on (factura.rbd = rbd.Id_rbd) ; me sale en blanco, si realizo las consultas independientes, es decir factura con rbd, o factura con cdn, se ejecutan correctamente y muestran las relaciones. El detalle es que al hacer la consulta de las tres tablas simultáneas ya no es posible. Pasa que quiero que al consultar una fctura me muestre los valores de sus respectivos dvi, cdn y rdb. Muchas gracias.

Muchas gracias a todos. les comento: la solución fué hacer cada consulta por independiente (factura con dvi) (factura con rdb) y (factura con cdn) y unirlas con union. Me arrojó los resultados esperados.

Te agregué una respuesta que abarca el porque NO deberías usar UNION en este caso particular, segun tu BD.

Pues primero comencemos con tu resultado encontrado y la explicación del uso de UNION.
UNION está pensado para unir los resultados de múltiples consultas, mientras estas NO ESTEN RELACIONADAS. Acá tienes el uso de relaciones entre las tablas, por lo que hacer múltiples consultas, en realidad, es innecesario.
Ahora, tu deberías usar JOIN, ya que se realiza una sola consulta, uniendo los datos relacionados de las tablas.
Ahora, porque no aparecían datos en tu consulta?
Lo más probable, es que haya sido debido al uso de INNER JOIN, en vez de un LEFT JOIN que es el más probable que hubieras usado acá. Al usar alguno de estos tipos de JOIN, se obtienen diferentes resultados, que deberías buscar para saber su comportamiento.
En tu caso, la consulta debería ser, para unir todas las tablas con sus datos relacionados...
SELECT --Seleccion de todos los campos de las tablas (ideal especificar cuales quieres)
    f.*, 
    c.*, 
    r.*, 
    d.*
FROM factura f --Tabla principal con alias f
--Resto de las tablas, con su alias y su condicion
LEFT JOIN cdn c ON f.cdn = c.Id_CDN
LEFT JOIN rbd r ON f.rbd = r.Id_RBD
LEFT JOIN dvi d ON f.dvi = d.Id_DVI;

Ahora, una recomendación clara, es que tus tablas, no deberían tener nombres resumidos, sino que los alias deberían usarse para ello. Esto igual debería aplicar para el nombre de las variables en caso de ser ambiguas. Esto es por que, de este modo son descriptivos, y cualquiera los puede entender (para mi rbd es rebelde jaja)
Te daré un ejemplo, inventando el nombre de las tablas con esos nombres cortos.
SELECT
    f.*, 
    c.*, 
    r.*, 
    d.*
FROM factura f
LEFT JOIN CertificadosDespachoNacional cdn ON f.cdn = cdn.Id_CDN 
LEFT JOIN RegistroBienesDocumentos rbd ON f.rbd = rbd.Id_RBD
LEFT JOIN DeclaracionesValorImportacion dvi ON f.dvi = dvi.Id_DVI


Excorpion tienes razón que detallazo, muchas gracias, ya lo apliqué y quedó 1A

Me alegro bastante, cualquier duda consulta. Recuerda darme +1 y aceptar la respuesta. (si, son 2 cosas diferentes, pero me ayudan mucho xD voy por los 5k)
